# Carousel images won't show in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, carousel

Can anybody tell me why the carousel images aren't showing up even though other resources are showing that is outside the carousel?

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <image src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/header.png"                 width="1000px" height="100%"></img>
  </div>    
  <div class="item">
    <image src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/header2.png" width="1000px" height="100%"></img>
  </div>                    
  <div class="item">
    <image src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/header3.png" width="1000px" height="100%"></img>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace you `image` tag

```
<image src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/header.png" width="1000px" height="100%"></img>
```

to

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/header.png" width="1000px" height="100%"/>
```

Comment: I must've overlooked it or something but <image> does work outside of the carousel, I changed to <img> this time but still the same problem.

Comment: I don't know why but after I converted the images to jpg, it worked.